# How to pop to specific view in the TabView Application in swiftui. I used StackNavigation also but not working in swiftui

Tags: swiftui, environment-variables, navigationview, tabview, swiftui-navigationlink

I am facing an issue while popping to a specific view. Let me explain the hierarchy.

ContentView -> 2 tabs, TabAView and TabBView
Inside TabBView. There is 1 view used ConnectView: Where is a Button to connect. After tapping on the button of Connect, the user move to another View which is called as UserAppView. From Here User can check his profile and update also. After the Update API call, need to pop to UserAppView from UserFirstFormView.

Here is the code to understand better my problem.

ContentView.swift

```
struct ContentView: View {
    enum AppPage: Int {
        case TabA=0, TabB=1
    }
    
    @StateObject var settings = Settings()
    @ObservedObject var userViewModel: UserViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView(selection: $settings.tabItem) {
                TabAView(userViewModel: userViewModel)
                    .tabItem {
                        Text("TabA")
                    }
                    .tag(AppPage.TabA)
                
                TabBView(userViewModel: userViewModel)
                    .tabItem {
                        Text("Apps")
                    }
                    .tag(AppPage.TabB)
            }
            .accentColor(.white)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
            .onAppear(perform: {
                settings.tabItem = .TabA
            })
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
        .environmentObject(settings)
    }
}
```

This is TabAView:

```
 struct TabAView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var userViewModel: UserViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var settings: Settings
    
    init(userViewModel: UserViewModel) {
        self.userViewModel = userViewModel
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Vstack {
            /// code
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            /// code
        })
        .environmentObject(settings)
    }
}
```

This is another TabBView:

```
struct TabBView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var userViewModel: UserViewModel
    
    init(userViewModel: UserViewModel) {
        self.userViewModel = userViewModel
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 10) {
            NavigationLink(destination: ConnectView(viewModel: ConnectViewModel(id: id!), userViewModel: userViewModel)) {
                UserCardWidget()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is 1 connectView used on the TabBView through which the user will connect. ConnectViewModel is used here to call connect API.

```
class ConnectViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    var id: String?
    
    init(id: String) {
        self.id = id
    }
    
    func connect(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        APIService.shared.connectApp(id: self.id!) { connected in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.isConnected = connected ?? false
                completion()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is connect view

```
struct ConnectView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var connectViewModel: ConnectViewModel
    @ObservedObject var userViewModel: UserViewModel
    @State var buttonTitle = "CONNECT WITH THIS"
    @State var isShowingDetailView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            if let id = connectViewModel.id {
                NavigationLink(destination: UserAppView(id: id, userViewModel: userViewModel), isActive: $isShowingDetailView) {
                    Button(buttonTitle, action: {
                        connectViewModel.connect {
                            buttonTitle = "CONNECTED"
                            isShowingDetailView = true
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the UserAppViewModel where API is hit to fetch some user-related details:

class UserAppViewModel: ObservableObject {

```
var id = ""
func getdetails() {
    APIService.shared.getDetails() { userDetails in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            /// code
        }
    }
}
```

}

This is UserAppView class

```
struct UserAppView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var userViewModel: UserViewModel
    @State private var signUpInButtonClicked: Bool = false
    @StateObject private var userAppViewModel = UserAppViewModel()

    init(id: String, userViewModel: UserViewModel) {
        self.id = id
        self.userViewModel = userViewModel
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text(userAppViewModel.status)
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: ProfileView(userAppViewModel: userAppViewModel, isActive: $signUpInButtonClicked)) { EmptyView() }
                if /// Condition  {
                    Button(action: {
                        signUpInButtonClicked = true
                    }, label: {
                        ZStack {
                            /// code
                        }
                        .frame(maxWidth: 77, maxHeight: 25)
                    })
            }
            
        }.onAppear(perform: {
            **userAppViewModel.getDetails**(id: id)
            
        })
    }
}
```

From Here, the User Can Navigate to ProfileView.

```
struct ProfileUpdateView: View {
    
    @State private var navigationSelectionFirstFormView = false
    @State private var navigationSelectionLastFormView = false
    
    public var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: UserFirstFormView(userAppViewModel: userAppViewModel), isActive: $navigationSelectionFirstFormView) {
                EmptyView()
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: UserLastFormView(userAppViewModel: userAppViewModel), isActive: $navigationSelectionLastFormView) {
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:  Button(action: {
            if  Condition {
                navigationSelectionFirstFormView = true
            } else {
                navigationSelectionLastFormView = true
            }
        }, label: {
            HStack {
                Text("Action")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
            }
        })
        )
    }
```

}

Further, their user will move to the next screen to update the profile.

```
struct UserFirstFormView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            /// code
            ///
            Button("buttonTitle", action: {
                API Call completion: { status in
                    if status {
                        self.rootPresentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }
                })
            })
                .frame(maxHeight: 45)
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to pop from this view once the API response is received but nothing is working.

I have removed most of the code from a confidential point of view but this code will explain the reason and error. Please look into the code and help me.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the navigation link with, tag: and selection: overload and let the viewmodel control what link is open, here a example

```
enum profileViews {
case view1
case view2}
```

in your viewModel add an published var that will hold the active view

```
 @Published var activeView: profileViews?
```

then in your navigation link you can do it like this

```
NavigationLink(
            destination: secondView(profileViewModel: ProfileViewModel ),
            tag: profileViews.view1,
            selection: self.$profileViewModel.activeView
        ){}
```

Then you could pop any view just updating the variable inside the view model

```
self.profileViewModel.activeView = nil
```

Comment: If this view model is going to be used a lot, maybe a singleton or environment object can help you better instead of passing the reference of the view model.

Comment: Yes, from UserAppView, this model is used in 7 views.

Comment: I am not observing this UserAppViewModel, I have created StateObject in UserAppView. I have edited the question. the view is not pop out even after activeView to nil. :(

Comment: I am not observing this UserAppViewModel, I have created StateObject in UserAppView and then observing in subsequent views